# Usar funções como parametros para outras funções é mais lento?

Tags: php

Estou pegando informações de um site que gera o conteúdo em formato **JSON** e surgiu uma dúvida sobre usar funções como parâmetro de outras funções, isso deixa a aplicação mais lenta? e se sim, como saber?

Exemplo:

```
$requestUrl = 'BlaBla.com';
$pageContent = json_decode(file_get_contents($requestUrl), true);
```

OU

```
$pageContent = file_get_contents($requestUrl);
$decodeContent = json_decode($pageContent, true);
```

Comment: Henrique, me desculpe, mas... onde há função como parametro de função? Aqui `json_decode(file_get_contents($requestUrl), true);`?

Comment: passei o file_get_contents() como parâmetro para a json_decode

Comment: Então... só para explicação, não iria responder a sua pergunta, mas é algo util, vc não está passando a função `file_get_contents()` para `json_decode()`, mas sim está passando o retorno da função `file_get_contents()` como um parametro da função `json_decode()`. Entende?

Comment: Entao primeiro será processado o bloco de codigo da função interior, para depois ser enviado o retorno como parametro para a função exterior.

Comment: Ah, entendi, obrigado por esclarecer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não. Em seu exemplo a diferença de tempo é irrisória, nem se preocupe com isso. Acredito que uma diferença significativa só será notada em funções recursivas que abusam de chamadas de função. Se quiser mesmo testar isso, use o código abaixo.

```
$start = microtime(true);

$requestUrl = 'BlaBla.com';
$pageContent = json_decode(file_get_contents($requestUrl), true);

$end = microtime(true);
$time = number_format(($end - $start), 2);

echo 'Tempo de execução ', $time, ' segundos';
```

Comment: Sem contar que o tempo de execução pode variar muito, de diversos fatores, principalmente em máquinas de desenvolvendo aonde o processo do php irá concorrer com outros processos.

A diferença seria na alocação de memória, um colocou-se em variável e o outro a saída diretamente para a outra função.